# Sizing and working with ICO files in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, icons, size

In an application I'm working on there are Images (part of `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`) being created dynamically in the code-behind of a XAML page and getting added to the window. I'm using ICO files, which contain various sizes and bit depths. The size I want is 96x96 @ 32 bit. The code automatically selects the largest size (256x256 @ 32 bit).

I'm setting the `Image.Source` property as follows:

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/Application.ico"));
```

Now, by searching around I've found the Icon (part of `System.Drawing`) which will allow me to set a string path and size, but this is a part of an entirely different library.

```
new Icon("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/Inquiry.ico",96,96);
```

Any idea how I can make my Image's size property a bit more manageable? Thank you!

EDIT:
[Convert System.Drawing.Icon to System.Media.ImageSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127647/convert-system-drawing-icon-to-system-media-imagesource/1127795#1127795) 
This post gets the image to appear smaller, however, it doesn't matter if I set the Icon to 96x96 or 128x128, it doesn't actually change the displayed image's size. I'm assuming it's going to some default value that is different that the `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` default.

EDIT to the EDIT: Weird keeps getting weirder. When I display through the original method, it's definitely displaying the image as 256x256. However, when I use the conversion method described in the link, while the sizes change, they are *significantly scaled down* (i.e. 256x256 looks closer to 48x48).

Comment: not sure, if i got the question, if you want to set a fixed size for the image, why not using Image.Height and Image.Width?
Else there are a lot of tuturials about reszing like http://rongchaua.net/blog/c-wpf-fast-image-resize/

Comment: ICOs are such a pain. It really doesn't look like Microsoft considers them first-class objects anymore... Anyways, system.drawing.icon.tobitmap could be used to resize an icon. Can you use the BitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth property inside a BitmapImage.BeginInit - EndInit block?

Comment: I read another post where the solution was to create the ICO a specific size but I can't find it now.  Are you using this as the icon for an applicaiton?

Comment: Blam: I was using it as an icon within the program. Sort of a pseudo-tablet-esque interface. It seemed to be touch-and-go for whatever size the actual system used, and then re-sized itself. Just ended up biting the bullet and made vectors instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try the markup extension that is posted in [this answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7024970/439024).  Note the use of `BitmapDecoder` to get the required frame from the Ico file.

Comment: It looks like this might help me out, but unfortunately this was with my last job, and I do not have the source, so I don't have the solution to test it against.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the following code, it should work for ICO files:

```
Image displayImage = new Image();
// Create the source
BitmapImage sourceImage = new BitmapImage();
sourceImage.BeginInit();
sourceImage.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/Application.ico");
sourceImage.EndInit();
// Set the source
displayImage.Source = sourceImage;
// Set the size you want
displayImage.Width = 96;
displayImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
```

Answer (score -1):

I havent tried with ico files, I think could be useful here.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Resizes image with high quality
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="imgToResize">image to be resized</param>
    /// <param name="size">new size</param>
    /// <returns>new resized image</returns>
    public Image GetResizedImage(Image imgToResize, Size size) 
    {
      try
      {
       if (imgToResize != null && size != null)
       {
         if (imgToResize.Height == size.Height && imgToResize.Width == size.Width)
         {
            Image newImage = (Image)imgToResize.Clone();
            imgToResize.Dispose();
            return newImage;
         }
         else
         {
            Image newImage = (Image)imgToResize.Clone();
            imgToResize.Dispose();
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.DrawImage(newImage, 0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
            g.Dispose();
            return (Image)b;
        }
      }
       return null;
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
       log.Error("Exception in Resizing an image ", e);
       return null;
     }
    }
```