# How to display icon format in image control?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm use image control to display logo icon with .ico format

```
<Image Source="http://laodong.com.vn/favicon.ico" Stretch="Fill" Height="30" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Image>
```

But it is not display with  .ico format,If I replace to png format and it will be display normal.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952080/how-do-you-select-the-right-size-icon-from-a-multi-resolution-ico-file-in-wpf/7024970#7024970

Comment: @FlorentGz I don't think that applies at all ... for one thing, that question is about WPF, not Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You have to convert the image to another format than .ico, if you want to be sure that you will have multi browser compatibility.