# WPF icon size not same for all images being selected

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 3 multi-resolution icon files (.ico). Each one contains sizes 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64 and 96x96

The icon is being dynamically picked by using binding.

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
```

and following is the code where imageSource is being set:

```
_imageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(icon.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

the column in which the image is being placed has `Width="Auto"`

I know that having a single .ico file helps Windows pick the best size. However, I am facing a problem that the icon size is different depending on which icon is being picked

e.g.: For one image 32x32 size is being picked and for the other 48x48 size is being picked.

Why? Is there a problem with the code or is it with the icons?

Please note that width is *not* being set anywhere in the code.

Another thing that is confusing me is that all examples I have seen for `CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon` are passing Int32Rect.Empty as the second argument (i.e.: sourceRect). However, I haven't found some good explanation on how it affects the image size. Some explanation regarding this will be highly appreciated

Comment: Haven't you tried different values for sourceRect? Maybe you can force picking a certain resolution.

Comment: the problem is that I don't want to force a certain resolution. It should be picked automatically. However, for a single image, same size should be picked (e.g.: in the case I mentioned, the size for both images for be same i.e.: either 32 or 48) because it is affecting the layout of remaining items

Comment: Understood, but apparently it doesn't work as you expect. So you could at least try something else.

Comment: You could also try what IconBitmapDecoder gives you. You would also not have to deal with icon handles.

Comment: `BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri(...), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);` (where Uri could be a Resource File Pack Uri like `pack://application:,,,/Some.ico`) will create a BitmapDecoder. You can iterate over the BitmapFrames in its `Frames` property and check their sizes. Maybe that gives you a hint.

Comment: It's my understanding that the different sized icons within an ico file can be in any order. I guess your approach picks the first one. There's no guarantee an ico file will have a specific size in it. The designer doing the ones for our game initially added one for every size, giving a massive file.

Comment: The code here looks like it might be what Clemens suggests https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952080/how-do-you-select-the-right-size-icon-from-a-multi-resolution-ico-file-in-wpf